# Loop through list of URLs, run BeautifulSoup, write to file

Tags: python, for-loop, writefile

I have a list of URLs I want to run through, clean using BeautifulSoup and save to a .txt file.

This is my code right now with just a couple of items in the list, there will be many more coming in from a txt file but for now this keeps it simple.

While the loop is working it is passing the output for both URLs to the URL.txt file. I would like each instance in the list to output to its unique .txt file.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


x = ["https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000298/0001047469-13-002555.txt",
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001082/0001104659-13-011967.txt"]

for url in x:

    #I want to open the URL listed in my list

    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    test = fp.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(test,"lxml")
    output=soup.get_text()

    #and then save the get_text() results to a unique file.

    file=open("url.txt","w",encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(output)
    file.close()
```

Thank you for taking a look. Best, George

Comment: can' you do `for i,url in enumerate(x):` and use `i` to build the url file name?

Comment: I'm going with that! Nice explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different filename for each item in the list like below:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


x = ["https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000298/0001047469-13-002555.txt",
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001082/0001104659-13-011967.txt"]

for index , url in enumerate(x):

    #I want to open the URL listed in my list

    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    test = fp.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(test,"lxml")
    output=soup.get_text()

    #and then save the get_text() results to a unique file.

    file=open("url%s.txt" % index,"w",encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(output)
    file.close()
```